# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\latys\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe"

Tags: python, pip

CMD can't see my pip comand after changing the path
but when i run any comand with pip like that python -m pip ... it works

I have changed a drive where i keep python from C to D drive and changed Path but it doesn't work

Comment: The path to Python is stored in the `pip.exe` file. Unfortunately the creation process of these files is undocumented. You can find a hex editor (which supports inserting and deletion of bytes in the middle of a file) and change the path which is placed near the end of the file.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you did. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. When you [edit] your Q, keep in mind that nobody here knows what you're doing, what your intentions are and what you observed in response to your actions.